# Error 7 out of memory with Selenium and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I've installed the SeleniumWrapper from Git and whenever I try to launch the simpliest code, I keep getting this error 7. I've also installed the latest chromedriver and put in the selenium file. The problem occurs wether I use chrome or any other webbrowser.

Here is the code :

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome"
bot.Window.Maximize
bot.Get "website"


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
 bot.FindElementByCss("#USERNAME").SendKeys ("ok")






End Sub
```

Comment: Did it ever work? I  notice you don't have a .Quit line in there. Open your Task Manager and see if you have been closing processes correctly.  Also, are you 32/64 bit? Chromedriver must also be on the environmental variable path (minus the ChromeDriver.exe part i.e. to folder level), unless you are planning to pass the path as an argument. The error you give doesn't seem to be about driver location though.

Comment: Well sometimes it works (like 1 in 20 ) but I get an error where it says that it can't find the ID or classsname. I'm running 32 bits Excel.

Comment: Make sure you close down processes. Use task manager to quit unnecessary processes. Then add a bot.Quit line to your code at the end. Try running a fresh. As to your __can't find__ issue: without an URL/HTML to work with it is difficult to say. If it works sometimes, but not others,  then it may well be a timing issue and you can add explicit waits to your code. If it never works (by class/id) then you need to verify you have the right selector.

Comment: I've closed all unnecessary processes, added a quit line at the end. The error is still. Excel tells me that the error is located at this point :    bot.FindElementByCss("#USERNAME").SendKeys ("ok"). Thanks for Your help

Comment: The same one, error 7.

Comment: I can't imagine it makes a difference but if you add the line  bot .AddArgument "--headless"   before bot.Start ?

Comment: I get error 6 (overflow)

Comment: Time for an office install repair? :-) Is this just occuring with selenium? Code without selenium type library reference is running fine.

Comment: I'm gonna check with an other computer  Nope everything works fine with other scripts without Selenium. Thanks !